# Saving view configuration changes in my Tab Bar Controller based application

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have an application that uses a tab bar controller.

The tab bar controller manages 11 views in total so there are 4 views available on the first 4 tab bar buttons and the rest are available via the 5th button named "More".

I have a couple of questions here...

Firstly...

Can i rename the "More" button?

Secondly...

When i press "More" and then press the "Edit" button on the navigation bar at the top of the view to go into the "Configure" mode and then re-arrange some of the additional views so they are now on the first 4 buttons (replacing the original 4 views), i then press "Done" and begin using my App again. However when i close the app and reopen it my configuration changes have gone and the App is back to its original state with the same 4 views on the first 4 buttons as was there when the app was originally installed!

(Just like the Music App)

The second question is therefore...

How do i make the new configuration save in my app so the next time the app is opened it is configured the new way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can rename the `More` button.

As to the second question: your `UITabBarControllerDelegate` will get messages at

```
-tabBarController:didEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:
```

You can catch the ordering change here, and then set `UITabBarController.viewControllers` to the proper order in `-viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

OK so i went away, did some more searching and reading and found the following great tutorial

http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-uitabbarcontroller-how-to-save-user-customized-tab-order/

This helped a lot (in fact it gave the solution with insights) so i thought i should add it here for others who do not yet know how to do it.